# How to limit the PHP DOM parsed listed item content from a div with same class name as other div

Tags: php, parsing, dom, web-crawler

I been trying to parse the content from a site using php dom parser code,

it works fine but unfortunately the individual div's in the site has same class name, so when i try to parse the content from an div, it extracts the data from the all the div's with same class name,

so , I put a limit to the parsing content from each div, now it works fine, but i recently faced another issue as , when the original site owner updates the contents in any particular div, the whole limit code goes into mess and extracts everything again.

The HTML of the site as follows:

```
<div class="newsblock-1st-col">
   <ul>
      <li><a class="itemtitle" href"#">some text </a></li>
      <li><a class="itemtitle" href"#">some text </a></li>
      <li><a class="itemtitle" href"#">some text </a></li>
      <li><a class="itemtitle" href"#">some text </a></li>
      <li><a class="itemtitle" href"#">some text </a></li>
   </ul>
</div>

<div class="newsblock-1st-col">
   <ul>
      <li><a class="itemtitle" href"#">other text </a></li>
      <li><a class="itemtitle" href"#">other text </a></li>
      <li><a class="itemtitle" href"#">other text </a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

So far my PHP code as goes::

```
<div class="newsblock">
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
        <ul>
            <?php
                set_time_limit(3600);
                require_once('dom/simple_html_dom.php'); 
                $html = file_get_html('https://milesfeed.com/');
                $elementCount=0;
                $i = 1;
                foreach($html->find('div.newsblock-1st-col') as $elemen) {                  
                if ($i < 1) {
                $i++;
                continue;
            }
            foreach($elemen->find('li a.itemtitle') as $element) {
                $elementCount++;
                    $element->href = " " . $element->href; 
                echo '<li class="itemtitle"><a target="_blank"';
                    echo $element;
                echo '</li>';                           
            }
            if($elementCount==5){
               break;
            }
        }   
    ?>      
</ul>
</div>
```

Now the problem is that i m trying to extract the content from the div with the class as `newsblock-1st-col`. But unfortunately there are is another div with the same class, and due to that reason it extracts the statements from other div of the class.

So, i put a limit break asking to break the whole parsing code once it extracts 5 statements from the first div, and then it runs the other parsing code which runs for the second div only. As:

```
<div class="newsblock">
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
            <ul>
                <?php
                    set_time_limit(3600);
                    require_once('dom/simple_html_dom.php'); 
                    $html = file_get_html('https://milesfeed.com/');
                    $elementCount=0;
                    $i = 1;
                    foreach($html->find('div.newsblock-1st-col') as $elemen) {                  
                    if ($i < 2) {
                    $i++;
                    continue;
                }
                foreach($elemen->find('li a.itemtitle') as $element) {
                    $elementCount++;
                        $element->href = " " . $element->href; 
                    echo '<li class="itemtitle"><a target="_blank"';
                        echo $element;
                    echo '</li>';                           
                }
                if($elementCount==3){
                   break;
                }
            }   
        ?>      
    </ul>
    </div>
```

And it worked fine as expected,. but if the main sites div statements has been increased or decreased, the whole parse code goes crazy. Like if the first div statements in html site add up 2 more statements making it 7 in total, the `if elementcount` command gets broken, making the parse code to extract all the statements from all div's with same class name.

I hope i m clear with the query. please let me know if you need further explanation..

Comment: What is the expected output from above HTML?

Comment: The above given HTML is from site "https://milesfeed.com/" site. while the php is to parse selective div statements..